# Framework not found (RoboVM Google adMob)

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, robovm

I am trying to add google admob to my Libgdx project that uses RoboVM. I followed the guide here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-mobile-ads/ios but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR] ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds
[ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
see invocation)
[ERROR] Couldn't compile app
```

However I followed the instructions to put the following code in the robovm.xml file:

```
<config>
  <executableName>${app.executable}</executableName>
  <mainClass>${app.mainclass}</mainClass>
  <os>ios</os>
  <arch>thumbv7</arch>
  <target>ios</target>
  <iosInfoPList>Info.plist.xml</iosInfoPList>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>../android/assets</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
      <skipPngCrush>true</skipPngCrush>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>data</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <forceLinkClasses>
    <pattern>com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*</pattern>
    <pattern>com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.particles.**</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.okhttp.HttpsHandler</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.conscrypt.**</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.BC$Mappings</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi$Std</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi</pattern>
    <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.AndroidDigestFactoryOpenSSL</pattern>
    <pattern>org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.DRLCertFactory</pattern>
    <pattern>org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.CryptoProvider</pattern>
  </forceLinkClasses>
  <libs>
      <lib>z</lib>   
  </libs>
  <frameworkPaths>
    <path>libs</path>
  </frameworkPaths>
  <frameworks>
    <framework>UIKit</framework>
    <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
    <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
    <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
    <framework>OpenAL</framework>
    <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
    <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
    <framework>GoogleMobileAds</framework>
  </frameworks>
</config>
```

EDIT:
Here's the build.gradle for iOS module:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

ext {
    mainClassName = "com.samuel.doubledodge.IOSLauncher"
}

launchIPhoneSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIPadSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIOSDevice.dependsOn build
createIPA.dependsOn build

robovm {
    archs = "thumbv7:arm64"
}

eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-ios"
    natures 'org.robovm.eclipse.RoboVMNature'
}
```

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` of ios module

Comment: Edited the `build.gradle` in. @AbhishekAryan

Comment: Is your folder structure ios/libs/GoogleMobileAds.framework ?

Comment: @TomGrillGames Thanks. That was the issue. I was putting it in the ios/builds/libs instead of ios/libs. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @SamuelM And what to do if your lib should be automatically imported by gradle?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who was having this issue, TomGrillGames' solution in the comments above was what solved my problem.I was putting it in the `ios/builds/libs` instead of `ios/libs`.

Comment: And what to do if your lib should be automatically imported by gradle?